# php concatenate

Tags: php, variables, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a var named $eventview with value of 3.
I trying to add the value in this link:

```
$link = "option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=" .(string)$eventview. "event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=$eid";
```

But the link is always

```
option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=355
```

with out the eventview value. Does any body can help me, please???

Comment: can you do `var_dump($eventview);` in the previous line to check the value?

Comment: In that case, `(string)$eventview` must be empty at the point of evaluation - have you tried dumping it out via `var_dump` or `print_r`, etc.?

Comment: yes I try print_r and have the value of 3. This is the value that I need to concatenate

Comment: Are you checking $link immediately after building it? Could you include a print_r($event_view); immediately before building the link and a print_r($link); immediately after? And show us the results of both print_r? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce this behavior (with PHP 5.3.3-7), maybe the problem lies in another part of your code (you may want to post a bigger part of your code to help us see what is wrong).

The following piece of code:

```
<?php
$eventview=3;
$eid=1;
$link="option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=".(string)$eventview."event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=$eid";
echo $link;
?>
```

produces the following output:

```
option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=3event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=1
```

Try to print the value of `$eventview` **just before** evaluating `$link`.

As mentionned by Firas Jradi, simply using:

```
$link="option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=".$eventview."event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=$eid";
```

works as well (and would have been my first try, although I'm not that familiar with PHP types).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$eventview = 3;
$eid  = "helo";
$k = "option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=" .(string)$eventview. "event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=".$eid;
echo $k;
?>
here only problem is you are not declareing another variable last written in     line
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried not to use the explicit casting?

```
$link="option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=".$eventview."event&for...
```

Answer (score -2):

After you have confirmed that $eventView does have a value - try changing this piece

```
" .(string)$eventview. "
```

to

```
" .((string)$eventview). "
```

Also

Try changing this line `$eventview=3;`
to

```
$eventview='3';
```

i.e. quotes or double quotes around it.

Please note: I haven't tested it but just a suggestion.

Comment: And why would that be exactly?

Comment: yes I use print_r and have the value, but when I try this:
$link = "option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=".((string)$eventview)."event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=$eid";
or this
$link = "option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=".$eventview."event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=$eid";
I always get:
option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=355
but I need
option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=3event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=355

Comment: Did you try adding quotes/double quotes around the value. I mean you are trying to use string types cast but the value is just numeric, it might be changing 3 to empty string.

Comment: Again, why? Why would PHP cast number to empty string? The only case is when you'd typecast an object that's implementing method `__toString` returning an empty string. Please stop randomly guessing.

Comment: why don't you put your answer here then you wise ones

Answer (score -2):

As @Wbdvlpr suggested i think adding another set of brackets will solve the problem, this sometimes happens in concatenation. I honestly don't remember the rules on this on the top of my had.

Wouldn't hurt trying ;-)

```php
$str = 'dsadas dsadsa dasdasda'.((string) $myString).' dsadasdas';
```

Comment: This solves [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Clearly not an issue here.

Comment: People are light on the negative feedback button huh? Oh well.